# Using "msoEncodingUTF8" with Win32::OLE in a perl script

Tags: perl, utf-8, ms-word, win32ole

I'm having a Perl script which saves a Word document as a HTML one.
The following code works:

```
use strict;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';
[...]
$go_word_doc->SaveAs2({
    FileName => $gs_html_name,
    FileFormat => wdFormatFilteredHTML
    });
```

In order to encode the output file in UTF-8, I turned my command in this way:

```
$go_word_doc->SaveAs2({
    FileName => $gs_html_name,
    FileFormat => wdFormatFilteredHTML,
    Encoding => msoEncodingUTF8
    });
```

The problem is that "msoEncodingUTF8" is seen as a bareword, and I can't find anywhere what I'm supposed to add for it to work.

Could anyone help, please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you find that "msoEncodingUTF8" is what you are supposed to give?

Comment: Well, it's a good question since it doesn't seem to work, even with the solution given by Ikegami (65001 being the intended value, yes). :(

I found it here : http://code.activestate.com/lists/perl-win32-users/31952/

Comment: 'Encoding' is also said to be a parameter of the SaveAs2 function in MS's documentation, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/word.saveas2

Comment: I think I'll ask my question in a different way! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The [`MsoEncoding` Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.msoencoding?view=office-pia) gives names to the Windows code pages. `msoEncodingUTF8` is the name given to the UTF-8 code page, `65001`.

```
use constant msoEncodingUTF8 => 65001;
```

Comment: I finaly got by with "use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Office [0-9.]+ Object Library';", but your suggestion also works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following command will create `msoEncodingUTF8` (and other constants) for you:

```
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Office [0-9.]+ Object Library';
```